# nginx - failed to open stream: permission denied

Tags: php, nginx

I try to test web site migration on a test server. Original site runs on Apache, but the new site will be served from Nginx.

Test server (Rocky Linux 9.2) is installed with Nginx + mod_security 3 + php + mariadb. It has been tested with simple index.php file... and it looks it works fine, however when I uploaded site code I got the following error:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to
> open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0Unable to open
> primary script: /var/www/test1.home/html/index.php (Permission
> denied)" while reading response header from upstream, client:
> 192.168.xxx.xxx, server: test1.home, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host:
> "192.168.xxx.xxx" open() "/var/www/test1.home/html/favicon.ico" failed
> (13: Permission denied), client: 192.168.xxx.xxx, server: test1.home,
> request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", host: "192.168.xxx.xxx",
> referrer: "https://192.168.xxx.xxx/"

I tried disabling SELinux, mod_security but the issue remained.

The /etc/nginx/conf.d/test1.home.conf looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name test1.home www.test1.home;
        keepalive_timeout   70;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/some_cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/some_private.key;
        ssl_protocols       TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;

        modsecurity on;
        modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsecurity.conf;

        root /var/www/test1.home/html;
        index index.php index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

}
```

Could you please advise on where the issue might be?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK... I have found the issue... It was file permission issue. After I changed owning user to nginx it works fine.